# Starting Mule for remote debugging without modifying wrapper.conf

Tags: java, bash, mule

I'm stuck on Mule version 3.4.0 due to requirements at work. I'm writing a service script to manage the service lifecycle of Mule and would really like to be able to have it hang and wait for a debugger to connect based on whether a certain option is present in the parameters.

I'm comfortable with Bash and implementing this, but I'm having an extremely hard time trying to get Mule to pass along the

```
-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=9989
```

to the underlying Java process, as it uses its own <sub><sub>(stupid)</sub></sub> wrapper to address Java.

I'm trying to modify the `bin/mule` script to have a mode called `debug` which will pass the above debugger options to the JVM when invoked with:

```
bin/mule debug
```

My current work [can be found here on PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/ZjS4as3j), and here is the relevant part near line 511:

```
debug() {
    echo "Debugging $APP_LONG_NAME..."
    getpid
    if [ "X$pid" = "X" ]
    then
        # The string passed to eval must handle spaces in paths correctly.
        COMMAND_LINE="$CMDNICE \"$WRAPPER_CMD\" \"$WRAPPER_CONF\" wrapper.syslog.ident=$APP_NAME wrapper.pidfile=\"$PIDFILE\" $ANCHORPROP $LOCKPROP"
        ######################################################################
        # Customized for Mule
        ######################################################################


        echo "command line: $COMMAND_LINE"
        echo "mule opts: $MULE_OPTS"
        echo "JPDA_OPTS: $JPDA_OPTS"

        eval $COMMAND_LINE $JPDA_OPTS $MULE_OPTS
        ######################################################################
    else
        echo "$APP_LONG_NAME is already running."
        exit 1
    fi
}
```

I cannot upgrade to a newer version of Mule. I need to find a way to modify this script to simply wait for a debugger when invoked with `bin/mule debug`. I've modified it enough to get into this `debug` function I've defined which is basically a copy of their own `console` function for starting in console mode. I can't seem to figure out how to get my debug opts passed to the JVM. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter `-debug`, following [documentation](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/34X/Step+Debugging), was present in 3.4.x:

```
./mule -debug
```

Give it a try.

Comment: The <code>-debug</code> parameter is useful when you can attach the debugger after mule is started and running. However, if you need to debug some startup code yo have to uncomment the 4 elements after the section "# Debug remotely..." in the conf/wrapper.conf file. Once you attach the debugger mule continues it startup sequence.